# Проверка значений data атрибутов

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два кусочка html кода с классами к примеру "one" "two", в них одинаковые дата атрибуты с разными значениями, которые будут подставятся динамически.
Как мне проверить одинаковы ли их значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkDataValue(selector1, selector2) {
   const elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1);
   const elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2);

   // здесь data-* ваш data аттрибут
   return elem1.getAttribute('data-*') === elem2.getAttribute('data-*');

   // или так, здесь дата атрибут data-prop
   return elem1.dataset.prop === elem2.dataset.prop
}
```

Почитать про [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: Подскажите сделал вот так: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejdbem но всегда пишет, что одинаковы, что не так?

Comment: @ДенисДоня хотя стоп, у меня пишет, что они "не одинаковы"

Comment: Да, там я сам накосячил. Спасибо за ответ)